# i don't know why iter(not __iter__) function use in this place,what is the mean of iter in this code

Tags: python, iterator

i don't know "self._iterator = iter(self._container)"in next code.

in django.http :

```
class HttpResponse(object):
    def __iter__(self):
        self._iterator = iter(self._container)
        return self

    def next(self):
        chunk = self._iterator.next()
        if isinstance(chunk, unicode):
            chunk = chunk.encode(self._charset)
        return str(chunk)
```

i read the api :

> Return an iterator object. The first
>   argument is interpreted very
>   differently depending on the presence
>   of the second argument. Without a
>   second argument, o must be a
>   collection object which supports the
>   iteration protocol (the `__iter__()`
>   method), or it must support the
>   sequence protocol (the `__getitem__()`
>   method with integer arguments starting
>   at 0). If it does not support either
>   of those protocols, `TypeError` is
>   raised. If the second argument,
>   sentinel, is given, then o must be a
>   callable object. The iterator created
>   in this case will call o with no
>   arguments for each call to its `next()`
>   method; if the value returned is equal
>   to sentinel, StopIteration will be
>   raised, otherwise the value will be
>   returned. One useful application of
>   the second form of `iter()` is to read
>   lines of a file until a certain line
>   is reached. The following example
>   reads a file until "STOP" is reached:

but i also don't know what the iter function made .

```
i know the __iter__:
class a(object):
    def __init__(self,x=10):
        self.x = x
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.x > 0:
                self.x-=1
                return self.x
        else:
                raise StopIteration
```

Please try to use the code, rather than text, because my English is not very good, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iterator can be iterated:

```
for item in mylist:
    print item

for key,item in enumerate(mylist):
    print key,":",item

for i in range(0,50):
    print i
```

To use `for item in X`, `X` must be *iterable*.

You can make your class iterable by adding `next(self)` etc, as in your sample. So with

```
class a(object):
    def __init__(self,x=10):
        self.x = x
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self.x > 0:
            self.x-=1
            return self.x
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Then you can do

```
 ainst = a()
 for item in aisnt:
     print item
```

Answer (score 0):

`HttpResponse` is a class that can store string data.  The data is stored in a member variable called `_container`.

Suppose `hr` is an instance of `HttpResponse` with data inside it.  When you call `iter(hr)` then you should get back an iterator.  This iterator will return data from the `_container` member variable.

This class "wraps" the `_container` member so that it can always return non-Unicode text.  Because this class has a `__iter__()` method function, when you call `iter()` you are really calling the special `__iter__()` method function.  This method function actually does call `iter()` on the `_container` member variable to get an iterator for its contents.  But then it saves this iterator in the `_iterator` member variable, and returns `self`.  Now it is ready to iterate.

There is a `next()` method function defined.  If the type of the `_container` variable is Unicode, it calls `encode()` to encode the Unicode in some encoding and return non-Unicode.  It uses another member variable, `_charset`, to know which charset to use for the encoding.  If the type of the `container` variable is not Unicode, it must be an ordinary string type, and the data is simply returned unchanged.

In this way, the object "wrapped" in this class can be iterated and always return non-Unicode text.

I am surprised by this implementation of the iterator protocol.  When it returns an iterator to you, it is just returning `self`, so if you call `iter()` twice, you do not actually get two usable iterators back.  This seems like it could be dangerous.  I guess Django code never does anything like that.